# printing first word in every line of a txt file unix bash

Tags: bash, file, unix

So I'm trying to print the first word in each line of a txt file. The words are separated by one blank.

```
cut -c 1 txt file
```

Thats the code I have so far but it only prints the first character of each line. 
Thanks

Comment: cut -f 1 -d' ' <file>

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To print a whole word, you want `-f 1`, not `-c 1`. And since the default field delimiter is TAB rather than SPACE, you need to use the `-d` option.

```
cut -d' ' -f1 filename
```

To print the last two words not possible with `cut`, AFAIK, because it can only count from the beginning of the line. Use `awk` instead:

```
awk '{print $(NF-1), $NF;}' filename
```

Comment: Thanks guys thats great. How would I print the last 2 words?

Comment: @ap1993 you cannot with `cut` alone, you could do `rev file | cut -d' ' -f1-2 | rev` or with `awk '{print $(NF-1),$NF}' file`.

Answer (score 35):

you can try

```
awk '{print $1}' your_file
```

Answer (score 11):

```
read word _ < file
echo "$word"
```

What's nice about this solution is it doesn't read beyond the first line of the file. Even awk, which has some very clean, terse syntax, has to be explicitly *told* to stop reading past the first line. `read` just reads one line at a time. Plus it's a bash builtin (and a builtin in many shells), so you don't need a new process to run.

If you want to print the first word in each line:

```
while read word _; do printf '%s\n' "$word"; done < file
```

But if the file is large then awk or cut will win out for reading every line.

Answer (score 3):

`-c` is for characters, you want `-f` for fields, and `-d` to indicate your separator of space instead of the default tab:

```
cut -d " " -f 1 file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
cut -d\  -f1 file
```

Where:

- -d is the delimiter (here using `\` for a space)
- -f is the field selector

Notice that there is a `space` after the `\`.

Comment: You can also write `-d ' '` to make the space more apparent.